# ios/android/windows-phone game advice

Tags: android, ios, cross-platform, windows-phone, game-engine

I would like to write a multiplayer game for ios/android/win-phone. No matter your device, you will be able to play online with others. My question is this: Should I write the logic in, say, lua, and write the UI independently for each platform (obj-c, java, c#)? Or should I develop the whole game (UI, logic, everything) with an SDK that supports all three platforms?

Comment: Lua is an interesting choice as I've seen game frameworks that support multi platform Lua development (Android/iOS). I'd be interested to see how you would tackle Windows phone.

Comment: well, lua is just one popular choice. i mean in general, should i choose a common language for logic and write the ui on each device, or just choose an sdk and write everything in one language?

Comment: I'm not a game developer so don't take my advice. However I would think developing the majority of your game in a common language would be advantageous. If you need platform specific stuff (ie. game kit, airplay, etc.) then drop into the platform language. With games I would think most of the ui would not need the platform language but it depends on what you're building.